# Why the mesh didn't follow the armature in the edit mode, how to get the coordinates of points on a mesh that defomred by armature?

Tags: python, blender, bpy, bmesh

I want to randomly deform an object by armature and get the coordinates of points on that object, but after rotating the bones in the armature, I just got the origin coordinates of every points.

I've tried:

```
obj = bpy.data.objects['horse']
mesh = obj.data
for v in mesh.vertices:
    print(v.co)
```

and also tried:

```
obj = bpy.data.objects['horse']
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
bm = bmesh.from_edit_mesh(obj.data)
for v in bm.verts:
    print(v.co)
```

However, both code got the origin coordinates of points. Does any one know how to get the coordinates of points in a mesh which follows the armature?

Comment: I found a button called display modifier in edit mode, but it just change the display, when I wanted to get the coordinates of points, I still got the origin coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use [`obj.to_mesh()`](https://docs.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_current/bpy.types.Object.html#bpy.types.Object.to_mesh) as shown in [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/68496/935).

There is also [`bmesh.from_object(deform=True)`](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bmesh.types.html#bmesh.types.BMesh.from_object) if using bmesh fits better with what you want to do.